# Import *.pyd file Cygwin Python

Tags: python, cygwin

I'm having an issue where my Cygwin Python installation does not recognize *.pyd files. It receives an ImportError: No module named 'understand' when attempting to import the *.pyd file. It is able to detect the file with os.path.exists().

I've experimented with other *.pyd files and have the same No module named XXX issue. I don't think it's a path issue as I tried putting .py files in the folder and was able to call them for other folders. What could I do to troubleshoot this issue?

```
(Mon Nov-11 4:42:49pm)-(CPU 27.4%:0:Net)-(ssia:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/SciTools/bin/pc-win64/python)-(11M:2)
 python3
Python 3.4.5 (default, Oct 10 2016, 14:41:48)
[GCC 5.4.0] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
import understand
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'understand'
 import os
 os.path.exists("understand.pyd")
True
```

Comment: Are you able to import normal `.py` scripts?

Comment: Also, what is the output of `import sys; sys.path`?

Comment: Yes I am able to import normal .py scripts.

The output of sys.path is:

['', '/cygdrive/c/Program Files/SciTools/bin/pc-win64/Python', '/usr/lib/python34.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-cygwin', '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages']

Comment: On the [scitools docs](https://scitools.com/new-python-api/) it mentions "Also if you did not add Understand to the Path variable during installation, you will need to add the SciTools/bin/<System> directory to PATH." So, I think in your `sys.path` maybe you need to append `'/cygdrive/c/Program Files/SciTools/bin/pc-win64'` ?

Comment: Hm, I appended that to both the the PYTHONPATH as well as the PATH directory, but still have the same issue: ImportError: No module named 'understand'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, solved.... In some sense.

Cygwin's python does not allow the import of *.pyd files. I was forced to install a new version of python and use that instead.